# Log 50X Errors Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx setup with one nginx server and cluster of four php-fpm instances running on back end on different machines.I have custom pages for 500,502,504 errors which works fine. What happens some times suddenly I got 50X custom error page and when I do subsequent refresh for same URL it servers URL without any error.

I wants to know/log reasons for the same behavior of Nginx.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should have access and error logs somewhere.

Comment: I have disabled nginx access log and error log both. I wants only to log 50x errors not notice/warnings. please suggest.

Comment: Suggest: enable error and access log. Latest access log has option to write logs only for some conditions. See `if=condition` modifier. error log has several levels of verbosity. Level `error` should be good enough

Comment: Hi Alex, Is there any option if I got any 50x error then refresh the same page without showing any custom page because what happens sometimes my site all of sudden gives 50x for any url and on subsequent refresh url works properly which means the error is not persistent and comes occasionally.

Comment: Response with html that will refresh page

Comment: Usually this behavior come from heterogeneous backends, where some are 'healthy' and some are not for the same URL. You should play this request against each backend separately. If you have no way of doing that/do not know how to do it, I suggest you activate logs (at least temporarily) on the Web-server side until this event is catched. You should customize the log format at least with the backend having served each requests and check if there is a correlation between error occurrences and selected upstream(s).